# Golang unable to map XML to Struct

Tags: go

I want to map XML data to Struct object. I have following code:

```
package main
import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    type FileDetails struct {
        XMLName   xml.Name `xml:"FileDetails"`
        FileName string
        FileSize string
    }

    type DataRequest struct {
        XMLName   xml.Name `xml:"Data"`
        DataRequestList []FileDetails
    }

    type Request struct {
        XMLName   xml.Name `xml:"Request"`
        DataReqObject DataRequest `xml:"Data"`
    }
    req := Request{}

    data := `
        <Request>
            <Data>
                <FileDetails>
                    <FileName>abc</FileSize>
                    <FileSize>10</FileSize>
                </FileDetails>
                <FileDetails>
                    <FileName>pqr</FileSize>
                    <FileSize>20</FileSize>
                </FileDetails>
            </Data>
        </Request>
    `
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("XMLName: %#v\n", req.XMLName)
    fmt.Printf("XMLName: %v\n", req.DataReqObject)
    fmt.Printf("XMLName: %v\n", req.DataReqObject.DataRequestList[0])
}
```

This can also be accessed here:
https://play.golang.org/p/VAMM9M2CejH

I'm getting following output with the above code:

```
XMLName: xml.Name{Space:"", Local:"Request"}
Data: {{ Data} []}
panic: runtime error: index out of range
```

Do the structs need to have diffferent structure for my data? Why is this mapping failing?

Comment: Add a tag to `DataRequestList` field. `DataRequestList []FileDetails \`xml:"FileDetails"\``. However the fields of your `FileDetails` struct and of the corresponding xml don't match, so that won't be fixed until you make the proper changes. (Oops they do match in the question, although not in the linked code) https://play.golang.org/p/IlcybvQBI9P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three problems with your snippet:

#### #1

The tag `xml:"FileDetails"` is missing on `DataRequestList`

---

#### #2

The `FileDetails` struct does not match your xml in the provided playground link!

---

#### #3

`<FileName>` tag is closed with `</FileSize>` tag!

---

[Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ONAJkqfgMkr) working example!